# Where are commas used with multiple if conditions that precede a statement (i.e. If [A] and if [B] then [C])?

Tags: punctuation, commas, conditionals

E.g.

> If it rains tommorow, and if I don't have an umbrella, I will get wet.

Or

> If it rains tommorow and if I don't have an umbrella, I will get wet.

Which of these two is correct from a punctuation perspective? I know that I don't actually need the second if here. But this is obviously a simplified example, so let's say that I wanted to use it. Would I have to put in that additional comma?

Comment: It depends entirely if you want *and if I don't have an umbrella* to be parenthetical (extraneous) text or not. If it's essential to what you're trying to convey, then do not use an initial comma; if the sentence would work without it, then add the initial comma. If you replace both commas with parentheses, and the sentence seems fine, then you can leave both commas; if it doesn't seem fine, then remove the first one. I can see an argument both for the second condition being essential and for it just being an aside.

Comment: I don't see any _statutary requirement_ that would stand up under fair scrutiny either for the inclusion of the first comma or for its omission here. Obscurity doesn't increase either way. As for style, I far prefer 'If it rains tommorow and I don't have an umbrella, I will get wet' to either. The clear winner.  But as for the minor places, I'd say that including a second _if_ adds a certain ponderousness (cf McKellen's delivery of 'Tomorrow ... **and** tomorrow ... **and** tomorrow ...') that fits well with the comma pause. _But a long way behind the winner._